# Add Image upload interface in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on wordpress. And has this kind of requirement, where I need to have an ability in admin panel for administrator wherein he can upload an image. This image will be used at two places in the theme.

I've tried to figure out this, and found that image url can be store in options table and can be used in the theme to retrieve the image.

But not sure how to give an interface for that in admin panel. Any idea to achieve that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not possible to use the built in [Custom Header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Custom_Header) image system? I don't really know all of your requirements but there is no reason to build something if you can co-opt something instead. :) Granted, it is called a "header" but it really doesn't have to be. Where it shows up depends entirely on the theme. If that doesn't work for you, you've got a considerably more complicated project but you'd probably want a [Theme Options page](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/02/creating-a-custom-wordpress-theme-options-page/).

Comment: I think theme option will be right for me as the image doesn't mean for slider or header image. Thanks

Comment: "header" is just a name. As I said, it doesn't have to be a header image at all. Basically everything is built for you if you do it that way, but I understand if you want a more elegant or specialized solution. :)

Comment: I ended up using options-framework. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your wordpress panel-> plugins:

install plugin named: `Custom Upload`

Or your can download it from :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-upload/

A simple plugin to upload any type of image in wordpress.

I think you can use it to manage your images of theme.

And that's it, good luck.